# How to mount a partition on an internal drive using USB live

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have some problems with my computer. I can't boot, so I've booted it using live USB. I wanted to check what's going on with my computer, but I don't know how to mount the partition.

On my disc (internal), I have two physical partitions, `sda1` (`/`) and `sda2`, which is divided into two logical partitions - `sda5` (swap) and `sda6` (`/home`).

`sda1` and `sda6` are not mounted. I was trying to type `mount /dev/sda6` in the terminal, but the output is:

> mount: can't find dev/sda6 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Indeed, the content of `/etc/fstab` is:

```
overlayfs / overlayfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sda5 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

The content of `/etc/mtab/` is:

```
/cow / overlayfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /cdrom vfat ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/loop0 /rofs squashfs ro,noatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/ubuntu/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu 0 0
```

If there is a need of any other details. I'll complete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's a good idea to check the usage description of problematic commands with the `--help` flag (e. g. `mount --help`) or in their respective manual page (e. g. `man mount`).

In this particular case you need to specify an existing destination directory to mount a device at. Example:

```
mkdir /media/home
mount /dev/sda6 /media/home
```

Since you're trying to reproduce the mount points of the on-disk system, I suggest you mount sda6 somewhere below the mount point of sda1, e. g.:

```
mkdir /media/root
mount /dev/sda1 /media/root
mount /dev/sda6 /media/root/home
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've check the man pages for mount, but I didn't think I have to create a directory to mount a partition of a internal disc. Why one partition is mounted "automatically"? Should I take it in account while creating this directory?

Comment: Do you mean the swap partition sda5? The live system is automatically looking for existing unused swap space to use for itself.